# How to put this two function in only one

Tags: php, function

Hey I need help I wanted to do two of my function in  just one, but I don't know why but I just can't do it like i want to.
Here is the code of my two functions

The first :

```
$users = User::getAllUsers();
```

And the second :

```
$userCheck = Suggestion::getIfUserWrotesSuggestion($user->getId());
if(!is_null($userCheck)){
?>
   <option><?php echo $user->getId; ?></option
}
```

Now the two functions work like this 

 The first :

```
public static function getAllUsers(){
    $db = new database();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnect();
    $statement = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `name` ASC";
    var_dump($statement);
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $statement);

    $userArray = array();
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $result['id'];
        $user = new User($id);
        $userArray[] = $user;
    }
    return $userArray;
}
```

The second :

```
public static function getIfUserWrotesSuggestion($userId){
    $db = new Database();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnect();
    $statement = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `suggestions` WHERE `user_id`= '$userId'";

    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $statement);
    $sql = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    return $sql;
}
```

I hope that you can help me. 
 Allready thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why would you do that? These are two different business requirements and should be actually kept seperate. Any specific reasons to merge them?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @addicted20015 Yeah i would prefere to let them like this, but my teacher want's that I do this in just one function

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel to do what the teacher said

Comment: Just a side note. You are instantiating the database twice (one time in each function). You should look into passing the database handle into the function instead to avoid overhead and write more maintainable, solid and testable code :D

Comment: Can you give more context in which this is used. As far as I understand this is for some kind of message/suggestion board?

Comment: @AnotherGuy yeah it's a suggestion board where we can sse the suggestion of the other peoples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to load all users and corresponding suggestions (if any) in one query.

Something like this will help

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    COUNT(s.*) as suggestionCount
FROM 
    users AS u
    LEFT JOIN suggestions as s ON u.id = s.user_id
GROUP BY
    u.id
ORDER BY 
    u.name` ASC
```

Comment: This would prove more effective.

Comment: Isn't exactly what OP asked for?

Comment: To judge from the code all users must be retrieved as well

Comment: What makes you think all users are not being loaded ;)

Comment: Didn't really help :/

Comment: how can i make this in php

Comment: @HugoPinto: The query above will load all the users with corresponding suggestion count(if any). You should use the field 'suggestionCount' to fit your functionality requirement.

Comment: @AnotherGuy:No worries. Happens to me all the time :)

Comment: @JA Oh yeah sry my fault. Did it for me Thanks dude

Comment: Pass the query above as $statement. And check the results.

Comment: @JA sry my fault your answer was brilliant did work fine for me and sry that i didn't understand in the beginn :)

Comment: @HugoPinto: Happy to help. Hope your teacher will be pleased ;)